# DB2 SQL How to get the last executed SQL-Statement with GET DIAGNOSTICS?

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400, rpgle

I want to call a procedure in RPG on IBM i with SQLSTATE and with a variable text.

```
getSQLMessage(SQLSTT: text)
```

The variable text should be the last executed sql statement before the procedure call.
Is there a opportunity to get it like this:

```
EXEC SQL GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 :text = last executed sql statement
```

Or maybe someone knwos another solution for my problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, `GET DIAGNOSTICS` won't return this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use GET DIAGNOSTICS, but you can first get the JobLog

```
DSPJOBLOG OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILE(QTEMP/ERR_LOG)
```

then get the last SQL Error:

```
Select Qmhmf, 
       Qmhmid, 
       Qmhmdt                                  
  From Qtemp.Err_Log                                         
 Where Qmhsev >= 20                                           
   And Substr(Qmhmid, 1, 3) In ('CPA' , 'CPD' , 'CPF' , 'SQL')
Order By Rrn(Err_log) Desc                                   
Fetch First 1 Rows Only
```